# delay not delaying in for loop

Tags: jquery, delay

I have a popup that I want to display a different message each time. Instead the .html() jQuery is run first and all I see is the last array item.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var popArray = ["App1","app2","app3","app4","app5","app6","app7","app9","app10"];

for ( var i = 0; i < popArray.length; i++ ) {

$('.site-footer h2').html(popArray[i]);
$('.site-footer').delay(1000).slideUp(300).delay(1000).slideDown(300);

}
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem here is you are updating the html in the loop and the animation is asynchronous so the loop will get executed first then the animation will start that means by the time the animation starts the `h2` has the last item in the array as its content.

```
var popArray = ["App1", "app2", "app3", "app4", "app5", "app6", "app7", "app9", "app10"];
$.each(popArray, function (i, v) {
    $('.site-footer').queue(function () {
        $(this).find('h2').html(popArray[i]);
        $(this).dequeue()
    }).delay(1000).slideUp(300).delay(1000).slideDown(300);
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/w7guB/)

Comment: thankyou, that almost works for me. But the html change occurs when the banner is up. I don't want to see the change over

Comment: thaks! the other version is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need `setTimeout` here:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var popArray = ["App1","app2","app3","app4","app5","app6","app7","app9","app10"];

    for (var i = 0; i < popArray.length; i++ ) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            $('.site-footer h2').html(popArray[i]);
            $('.site-footer').slideUp(300).delay(1000).slideDown(300);
        }, i * 1000);
    }
});
```